# django application getting error during template rendering

Tags: python

This is my directory structure of the project

```
blog
    migration
    templates 
        **blog** 
            __init__.py
            admin.py 
            models.py 
            tests.py 
            urls.py 
            views.py 

        **mysite**
            __init__.py
            settings.py 
            urls.py 
            wsgi.py
```

where **blog** is is the application directory and **mysite** is te project directory

This is my **blog/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

this is **blogs/static/post_list.py**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static "css/blog.css"%}">
</head
<body>
<h1>Testings django project</h1>

{% for posts in post%}
    <h4><a href="{% url "post_detail" pk=post.pk %}">Title:{{posts.title}}</a></h4>
    <p>content:{{posts.text}}</p>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

this is the **views.py**

from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from .models import Post

## Create your views here.

```
def post_list(request):
    posts=Post.objects.all()
    return render(request,'blog/post_list.html',{'post':posts})

def post_detail(request,pk):
    posts=get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    return render(request,'blog/post_detail.html',{'post':posts})
```

Here is the details of the errors below

```
*Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': ''}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:  
Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': ''}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 496
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:  
['D:\\djangogirls',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:  Mon, 20 Jul 2015 22:26:29 +0545*
```

Comment: Your error states something about reverse for post_detail which means you are trying to access the url for the post_detail view using reverse function. This error generally occurs when you are trying to access the reverse for the name whose url's hasn't yet been loaded by the server. Hence this error.

Comment: How what might be the solution

Comment: This is how i have imported the urls of application blog in the main project setting urls.py  from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'',include('blog.urls')),
]

Answer (score 1):

You should give objects names that refer to what they actually are. For some reason, you are using the name `post` in the context to refer to the *set of posts*; when you iterate through that set in the template you call *each one* `posts`. This, not surprisingly, confuses you so that when you reference the post's PK in the URL tag you mistakenly reference `post.pk` rather than `posts.pk`.

Name your objects correctly and this won't happen:

```
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request,'blog/post_list.html',{'posts':posts})

def post_detail(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request,'blog/post_detail.html',{'post':post})
```

and

```
{% for post in post%}
    <h4><a href="{% url "post_detail" pk=post.pk %}">Title:{{ post.title }}</a></h4>
    <p>content:{{ post.text }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Looks like you've not configured the URL dispatcher to include the urls in the `blogs/urls.py` file. Note that the main `urls.py` file is the one in the proyect directory. If you want to add another one in an app directory, you must do it explicitly.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) you can see the documentation on how to do that. Basically, you must add something like this in your `mysite/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Now you can access that urls, with the prefix `blog/`. For example, `blog/post/whatever`